# How to Keep Track of row index when JTable has been sorted by the user?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which has 1st row blank. Now when I sort the table based on a column by clicking on that column then the blank row goes at the bottom. If I insert something in the blank row and do the sorting then the row is placed accordingly. How do I keep track of its row index even when it is sorted. I need to access that row but if user does the sorting then i loose the row index as it is no more the 1st row.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `TableRowSorter` stuff added in Java 6, I think what you need to look at are the methods `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToView` in the `RowSorter` Class. You'd do something like

`table.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToView(0)`

to find out which visible row index is actually row index 0 from your model.

Edit: As Tulskiy pointed out in the comments, this may cause a NullPointerException if no row sorter is assigned to the table. Better to use the methods directly on JTable instead, e.g. `table.convertRowIndexToView(0)`

Comment: Looks like tulskiy pointed out that you can just call table.convertRowIndexToView, which will just forward the call to the rowSorter anyway but is more convenient. I'm not too familiar with these APIs -- I'm used to writing custom sorting before Java 6... yech :p

Comment: your code may give an NPE if no sorter was defined... and I had too many troubles with built-in sorting and custom table model to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 14):

[`JTable.convertRowIndexToView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView-int-) will return you an index of the row in the view based on its index in the model. [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-) will do the opposite.

Comment: @Krishna Kumar: no problem. I just realized I gave wrong description of the method :)

Comment: Its OK...I just did table.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToView(0)

and my purpose was solved...:)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1

There is some issue when using `jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(jTable1.getSelectedRow())` if you sort the values according to date or time will return incorrect values from the `convertRowIndexToView(0)` therefore use `convertRowIndexToModel(0)`.

SOLUTION 2

This will retrieve from the new model when sorted.

```
jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0);
```

This will retrieve value according to the original index even when sorted.

```
((DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel()).getValuAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0);
```