# Get object from selected JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have one JTable which show list of book and it can be filtered and sort

**BookSwing.java**

```
package com.bookretailer.ui;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

import com.bookretailer.modules.Book;
import com.bookretailer.modules.utils.BookDB;

public class BookSwing extends JFrame {
    private final static String TITLE = "Book Retailer - Books";

    private JPanel jpInfo = new JPanel();
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField txtFilter;
    private TableRowSorter<BookTableModel> sorter;
    private BookTableModel bookTableModel;
    private List<Book> booksList;
    private Book selectedBook;
    private ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BookSwing frame = new BookSwing();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public BookSwing() {

        setSize(600, 650);
        initData();
        jpInfo.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 650);
        jpInfo.setLayout(null);

        JPanel tbPanel = new JPanel();
        tbPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        tbPanel.setBounds(10, 331, 570, 272);
        jpInfo.add(tbPanel);
        tbPanel.setLayout(null);
        bookTableModel = new BookTableModel(booksList);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(bookTableModel);
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<BookTableModel>(bookTableModel);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        final JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(table));
        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeyList = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
        sortKeyList.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeyList);
        sorter.sort();
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
        txtFilter = new JTextField();
        // Whenever filterText changes, invoke newFilter.
        txtFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterBook();
            }

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterBook();
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterBook();
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                initDetail(table.getSelectedRow());
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setBounds(6, 37, 558, 225);
        tbPanel.add(scrollPane);
        listSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        table.setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel);
        listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionHandler());
        table.setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel);

        JLabel lblBookFilter = new JLabel("Book Filter");
        lblBookFilter.setBounds(10, 10, 78, 25);
        tbPanel.add(lblBookFilter);

        txtFilter.setBounds(75, 10, 489, 25);
        tbPanel.add(txtFilter);
        txtFilter.setColumns(10);
        getContentPane().add(jpInfo);

    }

    private void initData() {
        booksList = BookDB.getBookList();
    }

    protected void initDetail(int selectedRow) {
        selectedBook = booksList.get(selectedRow);
    }

    private void refreshTableData() {
        table.revalidate();
        table.repaint();
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        bookTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    private void filterBook() {
        RowFilter<TableModel, Object> rf = null;
        // If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
        try {
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + txtFilter.getText());
        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    class BookTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        List<Book> booksList;

        String[] headerList = { "Book Code", "Title", "Price" };
        Class[] classes = { Integer.class, String.class, Double.class };

        public BookTableModel(List<Book> list) {
            booksList = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return headerList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return booksList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return classes[arg0];
        }

        // this method is called to set the value of each cell
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Book entity = null;
            entity = booksList.get(row);
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return entity.getBookId();
            case 1:
                return entity.getTitle();
            case 2:
                return entity.getPrice();
            default:
                return "";
            }
        }

        // This method will be used to display the name of columns
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return headerList[col];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            Book entity = null;
            entity = booksList.get(row);
            switch (col) {
            case 0:
                entity.setBookId((Integer) value);
                break;
            case 1:
                entity.setTitle((String) value);
                break;
            case 2:
                entity.setPrice((Double) value);
                break;
            default:
                break;

            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

    }

    private static class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        TableCellRenderer renderer;

        public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        }
    }

    class ListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
                int lead = model.getLeadSelectionIndex();
                setFields(lead);

            }
        }
    }

    private void setFields(int index) {

        System.out.println(booksList.get(index).getTitle());
    }

}
```

i want set selectedBook when user clicked on table row
it works fine when user doesnt filter or sort data but when user sort data selectedBook is assigned wrong book

how can i make it work so that right book is assigned to selectedBook

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this code:

```
selectedBook = booksList.get(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to translate the row index in the view to an index in your model. These are different things if you allow sorting. This is covered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151850/how-to-keep-track-of-row-index-when-jtable-has-been-sorted-by-the-user). In your case, you should do:

```
selectedBook = booksList.get(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow));
```

Answer (score 1):

int index = table.getSelectRow();
Book book = booksList.get(index);